# Play Framework as a WebSocket Client

Tags: playframework, websocket, akka

I am using Play 2.3, was checking out the documentation for using Akka as a WebSocket Server. However in documentation they did not indicate if Play could connect to the existing WebSocket Servers. Basically I am interested in being a WebSocket Client who will receive messages from the WebSocket Server. My Play app will make bidirectional request/response with this WebSocket server then finally I will initiate the termination.

Is this possible with Play with Akka?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not as it stands. Currently it only acts as a server.

What you could do is use a client like [jetty websocket](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-websocket-client-api.html) from Play itself, and then process the data as you see fit.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your answer? How would the integration look like? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Checkout http://backchatio.github.io/hookup/

```
import io.backchat.hookup._

new DefaultHookupClient(HookupClientConfig(new URI("ws://localhost:8080/thesocket"))) {

  def receive = {
    case Disconnected(_) ⇒ 
      println("The websocket to " + uri.toASCIIString + " disconnected.")
    case TextMessage(message) ⇒ {
      println("RECV: " + message)
      send("ECHO: " + message)
    }
  }

  connect() onSuccess {
    case Success ⇒
      println("The websocket is connected to:"+this.uri.toASCIIString+".")
      system.scheduler.schedule(0 seconds, 1 second) {
        send("message " + messageCounter.incrementAndGet().toString)
      }
    case _ ⇒
  }
}
```