# Scala Play WebSockets

Tags: java, scala, playframework, websocket

As I've implemented a WebSocket server using the Node.js *ws* library, now I would like to push messages from a Scala application to that server. For that, I went through the [docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaWebSockets), which unfortunately is quite limiting.

My question is, how exactly using the Play Scala library can I send String messages to the websocket server of mine?

So far, I've tried the following:

```
def socket = WebSocket.using[String] {request =>
   val in = Iteratee.ignore[String]
   val out = Enumerator(logMessage).andThen(Enumerator.eof)

   (in, out)
}
```

But I cannot unfortunately find a method of providing with the *ws://host:port* URI.

What is the correct way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

When you define `def socket = ...` you are defining a WebScoket server. Here you need a WebSocket client. You have some solutions in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26805268/play-framework-as-a-websocket-client) or you can try to use the [http client](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.7/scala/http/client-side/websocket-support.html) from Akka.